# Drawing from MySQL using a search term PHP. I don't know what is going wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a bit of a problem. I am trying to draw data from MySQL using PHP and a search term. However I cant seem to figure out why my code is returning errors.

The Error I keep getting is:

> Trying to get property of non-object. Line 40

As far as I am aware this means that I am calling on a variable that either A. Must not exist or B. Has no value/s. I have probably made some stupid mistake but does anyone know why my code is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <?php
            $boxnumber = $_POST['boxnumber'];
            if (is_numeric($boxnumber)) {

            }
            else {
            echo 'Please only input numbers';
            }

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "testing";

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $query_boxinfo = 'SELECT box_number, client_number, client_code, tax_year, status FROM testing_table WHERE box_number=$boxnumber';
            $boxinfo_result = $conn->query($query_boxinfo);
            ?>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Box <?php echo $boxnumber; ?> Details</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Box Number</td>
                <td>Client Code</td>
                <td>Client Name</td>
                <td>Tax Year</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                if ($boxinfo_result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while  ($row = $boxinfo_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>';
                                echo $boxnumber;
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                                echo $row["client_code"];
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                                echo $row["client_name"];
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                                echo $row["tax_year"];
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                                echo $row["status"];
                            echo '</td>';
                         echo '</tr>';
                     }
                 }
                 else {
                     echo '<span style="color:red">Unknown error. No Results found. Please contact your System Administrator or Workplace Head.</span>';
                 }
             ?>
         </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You cannot use variables between single quotes. You have to use double quotes or end the string and concatenate, like this:  `$query_boxinfo = 'SELECT box_number, client_number, client_code, tax_year, status FROM testing_table WHERE box_number=' . $boxnumber;` See line 23

Comment: That `is_numeric` validation does not stop does not stop the script from executing further

Comment: Hmmm. I tried putting the variable outside the single quote and it did not work. And @HankyPanky I am confused on what you mean. Do you mean to end the script? And if how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Erik says is right, we cant use variabels between single quotes.
The query statement needs to be in double quotes.

$boxinfo_result is null here so you are getting that error.

Sorry saw your comment bit later, am unable to comment.
This will resolve
$boxinfo_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) instead of $boxinfo_result->fetch_assoc()

Comment: Check if $boxinfo_result  has valid resource object or not